# How to package "shiny" in R program?

Tags: r, shiny, exe

I have a problem with R program.
I have already done my program(.R file) with the "shiny" package, and have checked my program can be run in IDE(R studio).
I hope that my program can be packaged to ".exe" file.

thanks

I have tried to surf the internet about the packaging method.
But there is no completed information.
So what should I do? Is anybody can show the detailed procedure about the packaging method?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to generate a .exe file out of a shiny app. You always need a server like ShinyServer or ShinyProxy. Alternatively, you can use the new py-shiny in Python which doesn't need a server, however it is still in alpha.